# How to implement a function returning an AsyncSequence, whose results relies on another AsyncSequence

Tags: swift

I'm trying to implement a function which returns an AsyncStream of BlurredImage objects. The functions relies on another function sourceImages(), which itself is an AsyncStream.

I get this error on line 2 of my snippet:

`Cannot pass function of type '(AsyncStream<BlurredImage>.Continuation) async -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type`

What's the correct way to implement this?

```
    func blurredFaces() -> AsyncStream<BlurredImage> {
        return AsyncStream<BlurredImage> { continuation in
            for await image in sourceImages() {
                blurrImage(image) { blurredImage in
                    continuation.yield(blurredImage)
                }
            }
            continuation.finish()
        }
    }

    func sourceImages() -> AsyncStream<SourceImage> {
    ...
    }
```

I'm on Xcode 13.4.1

Comment: The present tense of `blurred` is `blur`. The other `r` is an anomaly encountered only when time traveling backwards.

Answer (score 3):

`AsyncStream.init` expects an input of type `(AsyncStream<BlurredImage>.Continuation) → Void`, which is not async.

But you can wrap its body in a `Task` to do async operations.

```
return AsyncStream<BlurredImage> { continuation in
    Task {
        for await image in sourceImages() {
            blurrImage(image) { blurredImage in
                continuation.yield(blurredImage)
            }
        }
        continuation.finish()
    }
}
```

Or as [@Sweeper suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72895837/15245033), you can use `map`. Based on your `blurredFaces` return type signature, you want to map `AsyncStream<SourceImage>` (result of `sourceImages`) to `AsyncStream<BlurredImage>`.

In case for some reason you want to keep its return type as that, I haven't found a built-in direct map from an `AsyncStream<T1>` to an `AsyncStream<T2>`, so I posted [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73425713/swift-map-asyncstream-into-another-asyncstream/73426577). In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73426577/15245033), I shared the `AsyncStream` extension that I created for this use case. I am still waiting for feedbacks for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing an mapping operation here. In that case, you can use `map` and return an `AsyncMapSequence`:

```
func blurredFaces() -> AsyncMapSequence<AsyncStream<SourceImage>, BlurredImage> {
    sourceImages().map { image in
        await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
            blurrImage(image) { blurred in
                continuation.resume(returning: blurred)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you can make `blurrImage` `async`, then this can be even shorter:

```
func blurredFaces() -> AsyncMapSequence<AsyncStream<SourceImage>, BlurredImage> {
    // you can even inline this, and get rid of blurredFaces
    sourceImages().map(blurrImage)
}
```

Comment: `sourceImages().map(blurrImage)`. Doesn't seem like it warrants a method.

Comment: @Jessy I didn't know you could do that! :D I thought the `await` would prevent it.

Comment: While the code compiles, it stops at `await withCheckedContinuation` until all sourceImages() have been generated. I was under (the possibly wrong) impression, that after the sourceImages async sequence had produced the first image, the blurrImage code would be executed.

Comment: @iljawascoding How have you implemented `sourceImages`? Depending on your implementation, it is possible for the fetching of the next image to not wait for the blurring of the previous image to finish. If the fetching is also very quick compared to the blurring, it may *seem* like all the fetching is done first, before the blurring starts.

Comment: I use `continuation.yield(image)` in the method that produces the source images. Here is the complete code: https://github.com/iljaiwas/FaceBlurrer

Comment: @iljawascoding Yeah I think what I said in my comment is pretty much what's happening here, except `imageGenerator.copyCGImage` isn't even asynchronous. You can put that in an async function and await it inside the for loop, then put the entire for loop inside a `Task`, if this is a problem for you. If you have trouble getting this to work, show a [mcve] and post a new question :)