# Swift: Map AsyncStream into another AsyncStream

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

#### Update

The accepted answer did not directly answer the original question, but helped resolve the underlying issue I tried to solve: I wanted to map an AsyncStream (which is an AsyncSequence) into another AsyncSequence with element type T2. I added some details in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73425713/swift-map-asyncstream-into-another-asyncstream#comment129667937_73425713).

#### Original question

I would like to map an `AsyncStream` into another `AsyncStream`. I wonder if there is a `.map` that can be used just like for arrays.

Quoting from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncstream/map(_:)-4a4la):

> Creates an asynchronous sequence that maps the given closure over the asynchronous sequence’s elements.

To code below has an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'AsyncMapSequence<AsyncStream<Int>, Int>' to specified type 'AsyncStream<Int>'
```

As I understand, it is because the return type of `.map` in this case is `AsyncMapSequence<...>` instead of `AsyncStream<Int>`.

Is there a way to just map an `AsyncStream<T1>` into an `AsyncStream<T2>` with a transform function `T1 → T2`, as it works for mapping `Array<T1>` into `Array<T2>`?

Thank you in advance!

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MacosPlaygroundApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup("Playground") {
            Text("Hello World")
                .padding(100)
                .onAppear {
                    Task {
                        let numStream: AsyncStream<Int> = AsyncStream { continuation in
                            Task {
                                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
                                continuation.yield(0)
                                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
                                continuation.yield(1)
                                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
                                continuation.yield(2)
                                continuation.finish()
                            }
                        }

                        let doubleNumStream: AsyncStream<Int> = numStream.map { num in
                            return 2 * num
                        }

                        for await doubleNum in doubleNumStream {
                            print("Next num is \(doubleNum)")
                        }

                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just remove `: AsyncStream<Int>` and let the type of `doubleNum` be `AsyncMapSequence<AsyncStream<Int>, Int>`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72895661/5133585

Comment: Let's say I have a function, input is some async sequence of data of a certain type `T`, and for each such `T` item, it does something with it (e.g. stores something about it in UserDefaults). For this function, it doesn't matter how that async sequence was calculated, e.g. whether it was mapped from another sequence or not. Ideally I would type it as `AsyncSequence<T>` (T being a specific type in my actual code), but `AsyncSequence` doesn't take type parameters. So I thought the next most generic observable type is `AsyncStream<T>`.

Comment: @Sweeper What do you think about [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73426577/15245033)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> Let's say I have a function, input is some async sequence of data of a certain type `T`, and for each such `T` item, it does something with it... For this function, it doesn't matter how that async sequence was calculated, e.g. whether it was mapped from another sequence or not. Ideally I would type it as `AsyncSequence<T>` (`T` being a specific type in my actual code), but AsyncSequence doesn't take type parameters.

I would suggest that you define this function to use `AsyncSequence`, e.g., here is a method that prints the values of the sequence:

```swift
func printSequence<S: AsyncSequence>(_ sequence: S) async throws where S.Element == Int {
    for try await value in sequence {
        print("Next num is \(value)")
    }
    print("done")
}
```

This will work with any `AsyncSequence` of `Int`, either the original `numStream` or the mapped `doubleNumStream`.

Then, as Sweeper said, you can just use the existing `map` of `AsyncSequence`:

```swift
Task {
    let numStream = AsyncStream<Int> { continuation in
        Task {
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
            continuation.yield(0)
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
            continuation.yield(1)
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
            continuation.yield(2)
            continuation.finish()
        }
    }

    let doubleNumStream = numStream.map { num in             // let it just infer the type for you
        return 2 * num
    }

    try await printSequence(doubleNumStream)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to constrain the associated type `Element` of `AsyncSequence`, it helps express precisely the function input type, better than `AsyncStream<Int>`. Also thank you for reminding me of `continuation.finish()`, in my sandbox I did add it, but forgot to update this post - just did now.

Answer (score 2):

How about extending `AsyncStream`?

```swift
extension AsyncStream {
    public func map<Transformed>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Element) -> Transformed) -> AsyncStream<Transformed> {
        return AsyncStream<Transformed> { continuation in
            Task {
                for await element in self {
                    continuation.yield(transform(element))
                }
                continuation.finish()
            }
        }
    }

    public func map<Transformed>(_ transform: @escaping (Self.Element) async -> Transformed) -> AsyncStream<Transformed> {
        return AsyncStream<Transformed> { continuation in
            Task {
                for await element in self {
                    continuation.yield(await transform(element))
                }
                continuation.finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you managed to improve that ? Works fine for me though

Comment: I think you lose cancellation support if you use `Task {` like that

Answer (score 2):

You can add:

```swift
extension AsyncStream {
    init<Sequence: AsyncSequence>(_ sequence: Sequence) where Sequence.Element == Element {
        self.init {
            var iterator: Sequence.AsyncIterator?
            if iterator == nil {
                iterator = sequence.makeAsyncIterator()
            }
            return try? await iterator?.next()
        }
    }

    func eraseToStream() -> AsyncStream<Element> {
        AsyncStream(self)
    }
}
```

And then do

```swift
let doubleNumStream: AsyncStream<Int> = numStream
    .map { num in
        return 2 * num
    }
    .eraseToStream()
```

Answer (score 0):

I too find this intriguing for a few things

1. Initially I used `map` as that is how we intuitively deal with synchronous sequences. As you mentioned in the description, that gives "AsyncMapSequence<AsyncStream, Int>" which to me seems like a leaking of implementation detail, as we don't need to know what is the exact type of the input sequence. Similar thoughts shared in Donny Wals' post [here](https://www.donnywals.com/comparing-lifecycle-management-for-async-sequences-and-publishers/).
2. I tried your solution with the `Task` block and it works totally fine. With an unmanaged task though, I always have the fear for it outliving the context and subsequently consume system resources longer than we wanted.
3. Again, the strong typing of `AsyncMapSequence` and its other counterparts (compactMap, filter, throwing, etc.) make them hard to pass around. The community had some [discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/anyasyncsequence/50828) on this but there are no leads on what could be fixed. Using such a type locally isn't a big deal, but their combinatorial complexity makes them not feasible to be designed into APIs that process various types of generated async sequences.

In our usecase, we end up designing the API by loosen the concrete type requirement to a protocol. Because the [`Element`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/Concurrency/AsyncThrowingMapSequence.swift#L94) in the `AsyncMapSequence` is defined as the second type `Transformed`, it allows our protocol to access it without a problem.